# Load WCF app.config bindings in edge.js app

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, wcf, edge.js

I have a WCF client for soap service, generated via SvcUtil that I want to consume via [edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/)

Is it possible to load an service model binding from an app.config using edge.js or
 will I have to construct the bindings in c#?

If I can, Where should the app.config live?

Thanks,

Gareth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running C# code within Node.js app using Edge.js, the app config file is `node.exe.config` and should be located right next to the `node.exe` file.