# Specify bindingRedirect for .net dll

Tags: c#, dll, log4net, edge.js

I have a .net dll which uses log4mongo.  In a normal .exe, in order for mongo to find the applicable log4net .dll, it currently needs a bindingRedirect specified in it's .config file:

```
   <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.13.0" newVersion="1.2.13.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
```

Unfortunately, I have no .config file to specify this in.  The common answer is to put this in the initial .exe.config of the executing program, but this .net dll is being run through node.js via edge.js.  Is there a way that I can specify a dll binding redirect either at runtime or through some other pre build setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170174/load-wcf-app-config-bindings-in-edge-js-app)?

I believe (though haven't tried) you can apply configuration to the node process by creating (if it doesn't exist) or modifying the `node.exe.config` file.