# Create a cloud service around node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have node.js application. I want to make cloud service for that so my node.js code can be accessible through azure service.

Solution : https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Azure-Cloud-Service-Projects

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve and what you had already tried?

Comment: Sure, I have legacy methods of c# which I am calling from node.js with the help of "edge.js".  legacy methods is all about creating some logs in the local machine. Now I want my node.js method treat as cloud service, So I can deploy in azure environment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550932/how-to-properly-call-synchronous-c-sharp-methods-asynchronously-from-node-js                                       This link was previous problem which I solved already.

Comment: @Pavol Pitonak:- I solved the problem through tool name is "Node.js tools for visual studio" (NTVS 1.0). It is facilitate to create cloud service for node.js app

Comment: @Sudhir Did you resolve your issues? If not, what's your question now?

Comment: @Peter,  Actually I made azure cloud service for node.js (worker role). So there I create server and assign some port So when I am starting my azure emulator then "http://localhost:1337" It print Hello World , which is fine as expected result. but when I am trying to import module edge.js in same file name is startup.js after enter same URL then It showing This page can't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue was similar with the SO thread [Load WCF app.config bindings in edge.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170174/load-wcf-app-config-bindings-in-edge-js-app/23480481).

Meanwhile, you can try to refer to the other SO thread about using `edge.js` on Azure WebApp, please see [How do I specify node.exe.config for web app hosted on azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891918/how-do-i-specify-node-exe-config-for-web-app-hosted-on-azure).